# Finding the maximum number?

Tags: java, loops

Ok, so I can't figure out why when I input an array of `1, 2, 100, 3, 9, 22, 58`
the following code returns `100`:
(this is just a snippet, this is part of a larger block of code)

```
double result = numbers[0];
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
    if (numbers[i] > result)
        result = numbers[i];
System.out.println("The max value is " + result);
```

But without the curly brackets on the if, it prints a list of numbers leading to the biggest one, starting from the first one, in this case: `1` `2` `100`:

```
double result = numbers[0];
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
    if (numbers[i] > result) {
        result = numbers[i];
        System.out.println("The max value is " + result);
    }
```

Thanks for your help in advance, this is driving me crazy and it's probably very stupid.

Comment: 1) all blocks should be enclosed in curly braces, all, even one line blocks. 2) learn to indent correctly. Your bad indentation and lack of curly braces is messing you up (I hope).

Comment: I suggest you step through the code in your debugger if you don't understand what your program is doing.

Answer (score 4):

In the second example you are printing within the if statement, so each time it iterates through the list, it prints out a result. In the first example, it does it after the if because you don't use braces. When you don't you {} braces after a statement, it assumes only the very next line is included in that statement.

You should learn good coding practices before you continue to code. It will help you avoid things like this later on when your code is much more complex. Additionally, stepping through the code will show you exactly what is happening, so you should also learn how to use the debugger.

Answer (score 2):

in

```
if (numbers[i] > result)
        result = numbers[i];
System.out.println("The max value is " + result);
```

the `if` block without braces only includes the immediate next line.

same for the `for` block.

**Explanation.**

the `for` does not have braces, so it will just iterate through the immediate next block of code, which is the `if` block.

the `if` block has no braces either, so it will iterate through the immediate next block/statement which is

```
result = numbers[i];
```

so effectively your  `System.out.println("The max value is " + result);` statement is out of both the blocks in the first case and hence executes only once.

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, result is being set to the current number (`number[i]`), if that number is greater than the previous value of `result`. This has the effect of updating result to the largest value found so far, as long as it's larger than the first value its set to (`numbers[0]`). If you print this at the end of the loop, you're therefore printing the largest number found in the array (max value). In the second case, you are always printing the largest number found so far in the array, as you go through the `numbers` array - therefore you are printing the numbers in ascending order.

Answer (score 0):

In the first example, the `System.out.println` is only executed once, at the end of the block.  In the second example, it is executed every time a new highest-so-far number is encountered.

Adding braces to both examples should make the difference clear:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    if (numbers[i] > result) {
        result = numbers[i];
    }
}
System.out.println("The max value is " + result); // only ever called once
```

vs

```
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    if (numbers[i] > result) {
        result = numbers[i];
        System.out.println("The max value is " + result); // called whenever numbers[i] > result
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

whenever you find a greater number than result you swap it with result and also print it out.

System.out.println("The max value is " + result);

should be right after the for loop (outside the curly braces) so when the loop will be over only the greatest number will be printed out.

Answer (score 0):

```
double result = numbers[0];
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
{
    if (numbers[i] > result) //this will check each array members to find the max
{
        result = numbers[i];//assign the array member if it is the largest
}
System.out.println("The max value is " + result); //print the max value of the array
```

Answer (score 0):

Read up on java and it's control flow statements.

If- and for-statements both have a clause - which is the code that is controlled. It can be a single statement or a group of statements wrapped with braces.

Read this:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/flow.html

Answer (score 0):

I'd review how to step through code with a debugger as  BobbyD17 suggested.

For eclipse refer to this [link](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftask-stepping.htm).

For [netbeans](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/debugging.html).